# is there a faster way to remove dublicates from one table?

Tags: mysql

I have a 184k-record table and have some duplicates by the key `concat(tradedate,stock_short)`. My approach is following:

```
Delete from levermannwithoutdub where recnum not in
(Select max(recnum) from leverman groub by concat(tradedate,stock_short));
```

Both tables `levermanwithoutdub` and `leverman` are the same at the beginning.

But the operation is taking now 15000 sec and is still working.

Is there a faster way to delete the duplicates where the max(recnum) of duplicates should remain?

I have tried to understand the try below:

[image: only one stock?]

But I still have about 2500 dublicates with max 38 copies of the same record.

[image: Here is my check]

How can I run it over all 2528 dublicates?

Faszit:
I have done the following:
 Create an empty same table with index unique to (tradedate,stock_short).
 Export the old table with recnum descending.
 import it via Workbench and ignore errors.

It took about 5 min only. 
I do know that this is not the sophisticated way, but its much faster than
deleting it by a SET of recnums.

Moreover: I found: [Tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows/)
 From where I did this:

```
    DELETE t1 FROM levermann t1
    INNER JOIN
    lev_mitdup_Lnotnull t2 
    WHERE
     t1.recnum < t2.recnum AND concat(t1.tradedate,t1.stock_short) = 
     concat(t2.tradedate,t2.stock_short);
```

Comment: Is there an index on recnum, tradedate, stock_short?

Comment: @J.R. at this time not. But I will do it, if it is faster.

Comment: My guess it that you would benefit greatly from a non-unique index on `recnum` and a non-unique index on `(tradedate, stock_short)` and also use your query without `concat`, i.e. `delete from levermannwithoutdub where recnum not in (Select max(recnum) from leverman groub by tradedate,stock_short)`;

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you have an index  on table leverman columns (tradedate, stock_short) 
avoid the concat for where and group by and use a subquery for reduce the search only at duplicated  rows

```
Delete twd
from levermannwithoutdub  twd
inner join (
  SELECT max(recnum)  max_recnum
  FROM leverman l
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  tradedate,stock_short
    FROM leverman 
    GROUP BY tradedate,stock_short 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
  ) t ON  t.tradedate = l.tradedate 
        AND  t.stock_short = l.stock_short  
) r on  r.max_recnum = twd.recnum
```

if you have more that value not only duplicated  but  triplicated  or more  you need  run the delete query another time

you can check how may valuue you have using

```
    SELECT  tradedate,stock_short, count(*) dup
    FROM leverman 
    GROUP BY tradedate,stock_short 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
    ORDER BY dup desc
```

Do the fact you have a lot of istance duplicated   for each  tradedate, stock_short
you could also try deleting all the rows that match tradedate, stock_short and are <>  that max_recnum

```
Delete  twd
from levermannwithoutdub  twd
inner join (
  SELECT max(l.recnum)  max_recnum, t.tradedate, t.stock_short
  FROM leverman l
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  tradedate,stock_short
    FROM leverman 
    GROUP BY tradedate,stock_short 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
  ) t ON  t.tradedate = l.tradedate 
        AND  t.stock_short = l.stock_short  
) r on  r.max_recnum <>   twd.recnum 
      AND  r.tradedate = twd.tradedate 
        AND  r.stock_short = twd .stock_short
```

Comment: thanks a lot! BUt I have of the same records 35 - 25 copies. I only could install a unique index after a while of operation. So it is a question which is faster, let your script run 35 times or my one with only one run. Thats a interesting question.

Comment: answer  updated  with a suggestion for avoid 35  repeated  execution  ..

Comment: Please see my updated question to your solution. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @sciasEdge  you have a wrong syntax: `Delete <table> from ..` see my update.

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair  answer  updated   delete twd  from